# How to detect checkbox clicked in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a javascript UI library as DHTMLX or YUI etc.
And I am using AngularJS to process dynamic page.
What I need is just simple.

```
UI code is 
...
<Input type="checkbox" name="XXX" />
....
My.js
...
app.controller('XXXCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.$watch(???){
   if (XXX) console.log("checkbox was checked!!!");
   else console.log("checkbox was unchecked!!!");
   ????
 };
})
```

I am new to AngularJS. Please help me!!!

Comment: Please note that should not use ng-XXX in UI code.

Comment: You can read ng-model and ng-change docs.  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="foobar"  ng-change="fooFunction(barData)" />

Comment: Why Angular then? If you shouldn't use angular directives ('ng-XXX') that pretty much enables angular

Comment: Try to look the second sample at: https://angularjs.org/ ... that have event with checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the value to the scope via ng-model. There is more detail in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D), but you can do something like that:

```
$scope.checkboxModel = true;
$scope.myAction = function () {
    msg = $scope.checkboxModel ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
    console.log(msg);
};
```

And in your HTML file:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="XXXCtrl">
    <label>Value1:
        <input type="checkbox" name="XXX" ng-model="checkboxModel" ng-change="myAction()">
    </label><br/>
    <tt>value1 = {{checkboxModel}}</tt><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the window object using document.getElementById combined with ng-click event listener

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.checker= function(e){
    
    var chkBox = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
   
       console.log(chkBox.checked) 
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='appCtrl'>
 <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox" ng-click="checker($event)"/>
 </div>
  </div>
```